# How to hide Navigation Bar Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, uinavigationbar, navigationbar

I have navigation bar, its opening clearly when user clicked left bar button... and I want to hide it when user click outside or slide bar to left.

This is my codes for opening navigation bar:

```
menuViewController=storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MenuViewController") else { return }
    menuViewController.modalPresentationStyle  = .overCurrentContext
    menuViewController.transitioningDelegate=self
present(menuViewController,animated: true)
```

Answer (score 1):

this is the line to hide/unhide nav bar

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
```